# Como fazer Select de todos os ids de uma tabela exceto os 2 primeiros?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Preciso fazer um select no mysql de todos os usuários de uma tabela, porém eu não posso receber os dois primeiros usuários da tabela e preciso fazer isso sem especificar id, já que quando mais usuários forem cadastrados preciso que os dois primeiros não apareçam. Tentei algumas coisas como NOT EXISTS (Outro Select), mas não adiantou. Não posso atualizar meu SQL portanto não consigo usar LIMIT, IN, ALL, ANY E SOME. Alguém sabe de alguma forma? Se houver uma outra forma podem me dizer também.

Answer (score 1):

Se está usando PHP podes criar uma query que retorne a quantidade -2(duas primeiras linhas) de registro e usar o valor obtido para chamar os resultados, excetuando as duas primeiras linhas

> Resposta Editada

```
<?php
//carrega arquivo de conexão do banco
include 'dbConfig.php';
?>


<?
// conta registros
$queryTotal = $db->query("SELECT count(id)-2 as id FROM tabela");
?>
<?php foreach($queryTotal as $row) : ?> 
<?php endforeach ?>

<!-- cria variavel de quantidade de registros -2 -->
<?$total = $row['id'];?>

<!-- chama registros menos os 2 primeiros usando a variável gerada acima -->
<?
$query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM tabela order by id DESC LIMIT $total");
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 

} ?>

            <!--  imprime valores na tela-->
            <?php foreach($query as $row) : ?> 
            <?php echo $row['id']; ?></p>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Miguel, não sei se você chegou a ler o outro comentário mas, tentei fazer o que vc disse e, mesmo que o sql me desse a mensagem que não pode usar LIMIT. Quando implementei o select que você me enviou, a página me retornou esse erro: ERRORSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT count(id) FROM bd_postagem ORDER BY id)' at line 1, sabe qual seria o problema?

Comment: Códigos que estou usando: $select = "SELECT count(id) FROM bd_postagem ORDER BY id";
             $select2 = "SELECT * FROM bd_postagem ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ($select)";

Comment: @MarcusLopes se puder colocar a query completa na pergunta ajuda bastante, tente retirar os parentese de `LIMIT ($select)`

Comment: Mesmo retirando os parenteses ele dá o mesmo erro: `ERRORSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(id) FROM bd_postagem ORDER BY id' at line 1 `, basicamente o que eu preciso é que ele selecione todos os campos daquela tabela mas ignorando todos os campos dos dois ultimos ids.

Comment: Estou usando esses dois códigos `$select2 = "SELECT count(id)-2 FROM bd_postagem ORDER BY id";
   $select3 = "SELECT * FROM bd_postagem ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $select2";`

Comment: Estou fazendo a query via pdo:   `try
 {

  $result2 = $conexao -> prepare($select3);
  $result2 ->execute();
  $contar2 = $result2 ->rowCount();

  if ($contar2 > 0) 
  {
   while ($show = $result2->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
  {`  dentro desse while está o código para exibir o que o select me trouxer

Comment: @MarcusLopes editei a resposta, veja se te ajuda de alguma forma, adapte à sua query, testei aqui e funcionou de boa.